# Send Extra payloads params in SNS notification register and get back same params when notification receives

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, amazon-sns, aws-sdk

I am implementing AWS SNS with AWS SES.

I am registering notification that calls my http endpoint handler and i am receiving perfect notification object. But along with notification identity i want to send my extra payloads that can be received when registered endpoints called. I am doing it in nodeJS

here is the snippet of registering notification

```
   var params = {
      Identity: 'myemail@mydomain.com', /* required */
      NotificationType: 'Bounce', //["Delivery","Bounce","Complaint"], /* required */
      SnsTopic: 'arn:aws-arnstring'
    };
    ses.setIdentityNotificationTopic(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    });
```

is there anyway to send extra params like `Identity` and `NotificationType`  ?

thanks in advance

Comment: What parameters do you want to receive?

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I just want simple string. Like { Identity:   'myemail@mydomain.com', NotificationType: 'Bounce',SnsTopic: 'arn:aws-arnstring',CampaignId : 'cmp1'}; I should get 'cmp1' back in Notification response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to b a mechanism for adding metadata, however... the notification should contain `source` inside the `mail` object, which looks like it would be the sending email address.

Arguably, there's no need for additional metadata, because there's also the `messageId` provided with the notifications.  This is the same identifier you got back when you submitted the message.

If you saved the metadata locally (or even in simpledb, dynamodb, rds, or even S3) under that ID when the message was submitted, you'd be able to look it up again.  If you don't save something with each message you send, then you don't have a way to "close the loop" and track the fact that you've received a notification of bounce, complaint, or delivery of each message to each recipient from SES.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notification-contents.html

Answer (score 0):

It isn't currently possible to send extra parameters along with the notification. You should submit this feature request to the Amazon SES team, either via the [Amazon SES forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=90) or through [AWS Developer Support](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/).